# What extent does a license cover database schema

Tags: license, license-compliance

In the context of a server side web application which connects to a database, for example a blog that connects to a MySQL database. The database may have tables such as users, posts, comments, etc. With columns such as user.name, post.text, comment.date, etc. Exactly what you would expect for a blog. The blog software could have any license for the case of the question but I'll say MIT because it's generally uncomplicated and not open to interpretation. To what extent is third party software bound to MIT in this case if it is capable of pulling listings from the blogs database? Maybe for a rest api, maybe rss - the purpose doesn't really matter. It must connect to the same database, make queries based on the blog's database structure, and then do something with data fetched from the blog, and in cases may update the data, however does not use any existing code from the original blog software. The SQL queries may be inherently similar but not the same. Additionally, the third party software will not intercept requests meant for the original blog, and may even be extensible to work with other blogging platforms as well.

UPDATE: To be compatible with multiple database servers with different SQL standards the blog platform uses an in house database framework to generate queries. Therefore there is no existing SQL within the blogs code base other than various schema files required for installation. Each query is generated on a per request basis during operation. However, by exploring the database in phpMyAdmin, a database administration tool, one can easily deduce the required queries to select, insert, and update required fields.

Answer (score 2):

You waive away the choice of license, but it makes a big difference.

The MIT license is as follows:

> Copyright [YEAR] [COPYRIGHT HOLDER]
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

This is **not a copyleft license.** To the extent that any third-party software constitutes a derivative work of the blog software, at most the author simply has to include a copy of the license somewhere in the documentation and/or UI. That takes maybe 15 minutes of developer time, unless you get into a bikeshedding debate about how the UI should be presented. Because the cost of compliance is so low, most developers will choose to comply in any situation where there's even the slightest chance that it is necessary.

On the other hand, if the blog software is under the GPL or another copyleft license, then the cost of compliance is substantially higher, and so it is more likely that the developer will have to have a conversation with one or more lawyers about whether or not the software constitutes a derivative work and needs to be GPL-licensed.

As for database schemas in particular, this is a form of API. The copyright protection of APIs is probably limited or nonexistent in the United States, but we're not sure exactly how limited it is; see [*Google v. Oracle*](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2020/18-956) for details. If the third-party software merely uses the schema to the minimum extent necessary for interoperability, that seems quite likely to be fair use under the aforementioned precedent (to the extent that schemas are protected at all, which is still an open question).

In other countries, the copyright status of the schema is similarly murky. The EU and UK protect the data in the database with [database rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_right), but this probably does not extend to the schema itself. Database rights are only likely to be infringed in cases where the person accessing or using the data did not originally collect or create it, so they are mostly the end user's problem, not the developer's.

Comment: This seems like an excellent answer, but I'm confused how it could be interpreted as being an API. I wouldn't be interfacing with any element of their code or any operating objects or service made from their code. The data is plain text, not serialized or otherwise formatted, and isn't dependent on their system to be created, viewed or manipulated. Can you explain further please?

Comment: @RileyLester: SQL is a programming language. The schema is an API for your DML statements (e.g. SELECT, UPDATE, etc.).